# Was Lothal fully liberated from the Empire after the end of Star Wars:Rebels?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In the last episode of Star Wars:Rebels, the planet that the show has often been based on, Lothal, is apparently "liberated" from the Empire's rule by:

> Esra Bridger, a Jedi Padawan, with the help of some mystic force-whales forcing Admiral Thrawn's Star Destroyer to a random point in space.

My question is, was Lothal *actually* liberated from the Empire?

Looking at how other planets are treated, I find it hard to believe that the Empire never set foot on Lothal again after loosing a star destroyer and their planetary garrison. From a military perspective, if a base on a far-flung planet didn't send any communications, that would look somewhat suspicious and warrant some sort of response, and the impression that I'm given is that there was *no* response whatsoever after Admiral Thrawn disappeared - **so was that really the end of Imperial Occupation?**

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lothal might be helpful.  Not sure how reliable it is, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was given in the finale:

In the discussion after Ezra's disappearance and the Imperial force's defeat, the following was stated:

> Not to kill the moment, but the Empire won't just let us keep this
> planet. We need to prepare for how we're going to fight back.

In the postscript set after the Battle of Endor:

> SABINE: The attack we all anticipated never came.

So yes, Lothal was liberated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain it was! **There were Rebel bases on Lothal** and when Lothal was liberated, there were still active bases. This means that they were likely able to keep the base running with all the Imperial equipment and supplies they captured during the Liberation of Lothal. And seeing as

> the Imperial fleet fled upon Thrawn and other major ships being **pulled into hyperspace by the Purrgil** (those space whales you were talking about),

I would say that **it is reasonable to think that Lothal remained free**. And likely as a Rebel base, which could have caused it problems later on, but that's unclear. We don't even have a fully accurate timeline for all of Rebels, so it's still unclear.